# about or just about?

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms

I'd like to know whether "about" or "just about" should be used in the following. If either is fine, what is the difference?

> Jack London was immensely popular **about** / **just about** a century ago.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

**About** means approximately, or *close to*.

On the other hand, **just about** is generally used in the following context:

> He was good at **just about** everything; a jack of all trades!

*(Mostly, just think that you can replace "just about" with "basically.")*

---

Specifically, in your example, the best term to use would be "**about**," and as a general rule of thumb, mentioning an approximate time period uses "**about**."